# Can't set up my town at careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, jobs

I can't set up my town at careers.stackoverflow.com. I've used it for a while back in the time just after lauch of the first version, and as far as I remember, I could write my town there correctly. And now every time I type my town in, seems that kind of geographical api replaces it with a small neighbour town located 200km away from capital where I live and which I try to set up in profile. Help me :)

Comment: Just a side note: it seems that this is a some kind of google's or yahoo's api bug, because I also usually get name of this neighboor town when I try to get weather reports on my iPhone.

Comment: What town is it, and what is it changing to?  We do have some problems with the API acting up and might be able to help you.

Comment: My town is Murmansk and it is changing to Apatity (both located in Russian Federation)